# {order_total} conditional {if order_total > 100}

Tags: expresso-store, conditionals

I want to offer manual payment option only if cart total amount is above 100,00 but {if order_total > 100} doesnt seem to work.

Any sugestions anyone?

Comment: Correction: Syntax error, shoud be {if {order_total} > 100} but then i get error because of the leading $-sign. Is there a way to not include the 4sign inside the conditional?

Comment: you might be able to strip it off. depending on which EE version you are it ccould be done with a plugin like streeng/ce string or natively with EE4 https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/variable_modifiers.html#replace

Comment: yeah, thx Jelle!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using streeng plugin, final code syntax that worked for me:

{if "{exp:streeng find='€' replace=''}{order_total}{/exp:streeng}" > 100}